# Dropshadow on swing JFrame with MenuBar

Tags: java, swing, dropshadow

I'm trying to simulate a drop shadow using non-expensive drawing rectangles, around a JFrame that has a menu bar, but the shadow is showing around the lower part excluding the menu bar.

Any idea how to achieve the effect on the whole window?

[image]

```
package com.dropshadow;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import org.nuiton.jaxx.runtime.swing.ComponentMover;
import org.nuiton.jaxx.runtime.swing.ComponentResizer;

public class DropShadowMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initFrame();
    }

    private static void initFrame() {
        final DropShadowTool shadow = new DropShadowTool();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -512601712971605848L;

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);             
                shadow.applyShadow(this, (Graphics2D) g);
            }
        };

        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -4799881378955761842L;
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                shadow.applyShadow(this, (Graphics2D) g);
            }

        };

        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(content);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,20,0,20));
        menuBar.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 255, 255));
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();

        menuPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        menuPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic('f');
        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exit.setMnemonic('x');
        exit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X,InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK));
        menuBar.add(file);
        file.add(exit);
        exit.addActionListener(e ->
        {
            System.out.println("Exiting - Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        } );
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu 1");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 1"));
        menu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 2"));
        JMenu subMenu = new JMenu("SubMenu 1");
        subMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 3"));
        subMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Item 4"));
        menuBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        JButton x = new JButton("X");
        x.setBorder(null);
        x.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        menuBar.add(x);
        x.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));
        menu.add(subMenu);
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("bla blah");
        button.addActionListener(e->System.out.println("bla bla button"));
        content.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        content.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        JButton jx = new JButton(".   X   .");
        jx.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        menuPanel.add(jx, BorderLayout.EAST);
        jx.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));
        ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover();
        cm.registerComponent(frame);
        ComponentResizer cr = new ComponentResizer();
        cr.registerComponent(frame);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();
    static {

        for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
            colors.add(new Color(0, 0, 0, 5*i));
        }
    }

    private static class DropShadowTool {
        private void applyShadow(Container c, Graphics2D g) {
            if(c.getName().equals("Charbel"))
            System.out.println(c);
            Insets insets = c.getInsets();
            System.out.println(insets);

            Dimension size = c.getSize();
            int x0 = 0;
            int xi = insets.left;
            int y0 = 0;
            int yi = insets.top;
            int width0 = size.width;
            int widthi = size.width - xi - insets.right;
            int height0 = size.height;
            int heighti = size.height - yi - insets.bottom;

            int last = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < insets.left; i++) {
                last = i;
                drawLines(g, x0, y0, width0, height0, i);
            }
            drawLines(g, x0, y0, width0, height0, last);
        }

        private void drawLines(Graphics2D g, int x0, int y0, int width0, int height0, int i) {
            int x = x0 + i;
            int y = y0 + i;
            int width = width0 - i - i;
            int height = height0 - i - i;
            g.setColor(colors.get(i % colors.size()));
            g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna guess that it's because you're adding the shadow to `contentPane` but the menu bar is being added directly to `frame` so it's outside the area that the shadow applies to, but that's a _lot_ of code to go through.

Comment: fair enough. how do I add the shadow outside the contentPane. I tried to override the paint() of the JFrame, but it doesn't have any impact.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that your drop shadow is just is just a custom Border and should be implemented as such.

Then you should be able to add the `DropShadowBorder` to any Swing component without doing any custom painting on the component.

Then I would suggest you can set the `Border` of the `JRootPane`. The root pane manages both the menu bar and the content pane at a higher level so the border should be around both components.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [The Root Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#rootpane).

Comment: Ok thank you with that, I'll have a look at how to implement a custom border. btw Thank you for your ComponentMover/ComponentResizer work! I just tried them, they seem to work ok, but have some niggles still. In the code above, I can't seem to move the frame down much. Below a certain point it refuses to go. I didn't get time to research what did I do wrong yet.

Comment: @Charbel, *I can't seem to move the frame down much.* The ComponentMover is designed to keep the component in the bounds of its parent. In the case of the Window is will remain in the bounds of the screen (and the desktop bar). Also note that when I run your code on Windows 7 using JDK 8 I don't see drop shadow border.